# In azure web app File.Exits return false actually file exists

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

We have a mail template in `~/Content/EmailTemplate/template.cshtml`. But whenever we do the following:

```
var path="D:/site/wwwroot/Content/EmailTemplate/template.cshtml"
File.Exist(path)
```

`File.Exist(path)` returns `false`. While debugging in local source it works fine. It returns false in azure web app only. I have checked the file already exists there.

Comment: Note that `File.Exists` will return `false` if the process under which you are executing the code doesn't have permissions to access this file. Could this be the case? In Azure maybe your code is running under an account with restricted access.

Comment: Hi @DarinDimitrov there is any way to check permission, But my account in admin mode only

Comment: Azure web apps files are in D:/home/site/wwwroot so that is probably your problem. But like mentioned you should not hardcode the paths.

Answer (score 2):

If you move the above code to another environment it will break.

I would suggest that you use map path as this will assure that you can move from hosting environment to hosting environment, including your local development environment.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/path/tofile");
```

You will also have higher confidence that you are targeting the file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure WebApp,
`D:\home` is shared for us and we could read or write file in this path. More detail about Home directory access please refer to the [WebApp Sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). File structure on Azure please refer to another [document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/File-structure-on-azure). We could browse it from Kudu (http://yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/) tool. In your case, we also could use the following code in the Azure WebApp.

```
string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + @"\site\wwwroot\Content\EmailTemplate\template.cshtml"
```